# Custom fields tag not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new in wp so.. I have div block with post data  like this:

```
<div class="col12">
 <?php the_post_thumbnail($size, $attr ); ?>
 <?php the_title(); ?>
    <div class="status">
      <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'status', true); ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

So this `get_post_meta` line works perfect with custom fields  in back-end and front-end, but I'm using `AJAX LOAD MORE PLUGIN` where you have to create theme repeater with same code as were shown up.

So... The problem is this theme repeater is not working with this `get_post_meta` tag(I think so?). I want to know is there something wrong in this line `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'status', true); ?>` or its just plugin's BUG? Just your opinion. Apologise for such question and THANKS.

[Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/)

WORDPRESS VERSION 4.2.2

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a link to the specific plugin and version information. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: I think you need to check how AJAX LOAD MORE PLUGIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO GUYS,   YOU NEED TO INPUT BEFORE THIS code   `global $post;` in my case it looks like this

```
<?php
global $post;
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'status', true);
?>
```